# Cannot push commit to a newly created repository on GitHub

Tags: git, github, repository, git-push

I recently just created a new repository on GitHub (just for me) on my account. Using the command line I navigated to a folder containing some files and folders which I want to push to the online repository using the command line. I the online repository just includes an initial commit and a single readme file. I used `git add --all` to add all inside the folder and using the current directory as the master I am still having problems pushing.

I tried using `fetch`, `pull`, `merge`, `rebase`, then `push` again but it is not working. Here is part of what i did:

```
Muaz Aljarhi@MuazAljarhi-PC MINGW64 /f/muaz/Programming/Java (master)
$ git push -u origin master
fatal: HttpRequestException encountered.
   An error occurred while sending the request.
Username for 'https://github.com': Muaz.Al.Jarhi@Gmail.com
To https://github.com/SamuraiHub/Java.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/SamuraiHub/Java.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Muaz Aljarhi@MuazAljarhi-PC MINGW64 /f/muaz/Programming/Java (master)
$ ^C

Muaz Aljarhi@MuazAljarhi-PC MINGW64 /f/muaz/Programming/Java (master)
$ git fetch origin master
warning: no common commits
remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
From https://github.com/SamuraiHub/Java
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
Auto packing the repository in background for optimum performance.
See "git help gc" for manual housekeeping.
Counting objects: 6350, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6164/6164), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6350/6350), done.
Total 6350 (delta 534), reused 0 (delta 0)
Removing duplicate objects: 100% (256/256), done.

Muaz Aljarhi@MuazAljarhi-PC MINGW64 /f/muaz/Programming/Java (master)
$ git merge origin master
merge: origin - not something we can merge

Muaz Aljarhi@MuazAljarhi-PC MINGW64 /f/muaz/Programming/Java (master)
$ git push -u origin master
fatal: HttpRequestException encountered.
   An error occurred while sending the request.
Username for 'https://github.com': Muaz.Al.Jarhi@Gmail.com
To https://github.com/SamuraiHub/Java.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/SamuraiHub/Java.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Muaz Aljarhi@MuazAljarhi-PC MINGW64 /f/muaz/Programming/Java (master)
$ git pull
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master


Muaz Aljarhi@MuazAljarhi-PC MINGW64 /f/muaz/Programming/Java (master)
$ git checkout master
Already on 'master'

Muaz Aljarhi@MuazAljarhi-PC MINGW64 /f/muaz/Programming/Java (master)
$ git pull
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master


Muaz Aljarhi@MuazAljarhi-PC MINGW64 /f/muaz/Programming/Java (master)
$ git push -u origin master
fatal: HttpRequestException encountered.
   An error occurred while sending the request.
Username for 'https://github.com': Muaz.Al.Jarhi@Gmail.com
To https://github.com/SamuraiHub/Java.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/SamuraiHub/Java.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Muaz Aljarhi@MuazAljarhi-PC MINGW64 /f/muaz/Programming/Java (master)
$ git pull --rebase
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to rebase against.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master


Muaz Aljarhi@MuazAljarhi-PC MINGW64 /f/muaz/Programming/Java (master)
$ git fetch origin master
From https://github.com/SamuraiHub/Java
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD

Muaz Aljarhi@MuazAljarhi-PC MINGW64 /f/muaz/Programming/Java (master)
$ git merge origin master
merge: origin - not something we can merge

Muaz Aljarhi@MuazAljarhi-PC MINGW64 /f/muaz/Programming/Java (master)
$ git merge master
Already up-to-date.

Muaz Aljarhi@MuazAljarhi-PC MINGW64 /f/muaz/Programming/Java (master)
$ git push -u origin master
fatal: HttpRequestException encountered.
   An error occurred while sending the request.
Username for 'https://github.com': Muaz.Al.Jarhi@Gmail.com
To https://github.com/SamuraiHub/Java.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/SamuraiHub/Java.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Muaz Aljarhi@MuazAljarhi-PC MINGW64 /f/muaz/Programming/Java (master)
$ ^C

Muaz Aljarhi@MuazAljarhi-PC MINGW64 /f/muaz/Programming/Java (master)
$ git pull --rebase
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to rebase against.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master


Muaz Aljarhi@MuazAljarhi-PC MINGW64 /f/muaz/Programming/Java (master)
$ git pull
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master


Muaz Aljarhi@MuazAljarhi-PC MINGW64 /f/muaz/Programming/Java (master)
$ git pull origin master --rebase
From https://github.com/SamuraiHub/Java
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...



Muaz Aljarhi@MuazAljarhi-PC MINGW64 /f/muaz/Programming/Java ((ec222e4...)|AM/REBASE)
$

Muaz Aljarhi@MuazAljarhi-PC MINGW64 /f/muaz/Programming/Java ((ec222e4...)|AM/REBASE)
$ git push -u origin master
fatal: HttpRequestException encountered.
   An error occurred while sending the request.
Username for 'https://github.com': Muaz.Al.Jarhi@Gmail.com
To https://github.com/SamuraiHub/Java.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/SamuraiHub/Java.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Muaz Aljarhi@MuazAljarhi-PC MINGW64 /f/muaz/Programming/Java ((ec222e4...)|AM/REBASE)
$ git checkout master
Checking out files: 100% (10551/10551), done.
Previous HEAD position was ec222e4... Initial commit
Switched to branch 'master'

Muaz Aljarhi@MuazAljarhi-PC MINGW64 /f/muaz/Programming/Java (master|AM/REBASE)
$ git push -u origin master
fatal: HttpRequestException encountered.
   An error occurred while sending the request.
Username for 'https://github.com': Muaz.Al.Jarhi@Gmail.com
To https://github.com/SamuraiHub/Java.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/SamuraiHub/Java.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Muaz Aljarhi@MuazAljarhi-PC MINGW64 /f/muaz/Programming/Java (master|AM/REBASE)
$
```

Any ideas on how to fix this other than uploading form the website and using the `--force` or `-f` option (I know it might not cause issues here but generally we should not use it)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the online repository just includes an initial commit and a single readme file

That's your problem. Your local copy doesn't include that commit.

I would probably fix it by adding the remote, fetching `origin/master`, *rebasing* (not merging) my local work on top, then pushing:

```
git remote add origin <url>
git fetch origin
git checkout master
git rebase origin/master
git push
```

Of course, if you'd prefer to merge that's fine too. But you have a syntax error:

> ```
> $ git merge origin master
> merge: origin - not something we can merge
> ```

You need to merge *`origin/master`* (a single argument naming a remote tracking ref), not `origin master` (two arguments).

Your `git pull` failed because there's no tracking information for `master`:

> ```
> $ git pull
> There is no tracking information for the current branch.
> Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
> See git-pull(1) for details.
>
>     git pull <remote> <branch>
>
> If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:
>
>     git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master
> ```

Git doesn't know which remote branch to fetch and merge into your local `master`, but you can tell it with `git branch --set-upstream-to`, as the error message suggests.

Please make sure to read the error messages that Git provides. They can be a bit dense, but they do contain helpful information.

> Any ideas on how to fix this other than uploading form the website and using the `--force` or `-f` option (I know it might not cause issues here but generally we should not use it)?

In this case, if you don't want the README that GitHub created, I don't see any harm in force pushing (though I'd recommend fetching first and using `--force-with-lease`, which is less likely to let you clobber commits you're not aware of).